# React props.children width

Tags: reactjs

Is there anyway of getting the width of React component children. I have wrapper component called for lack of name Container and I add children of div type from Component1 to it. See below example. 
I'm wondering if there is a way to get the width of each div child in Container when it mounts.

**UPDATED NOTE:**
The reason I'm trying to get the containers children widths is so I can dynamical set the containers width based on the total number of children. By setting the containers width to the number of children's width then I can allow for some horizontal scrolling effects I want to do.

**Component 1**

```
export default class Component1 extends Component{
render(){
  return(
    <Container>
        <div className="large-box"/>
        <div className="large-box-dark"/>
    </Container>
  )
 }
}
```

Now my **Container component.**

```
    export default class Container extends Component{
      componentDidMount(){
        this.props.children.forEach(( el ) => {
        // get each child's width 
        console.log("el  =", el);
      });
      }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="scroller" ref={(scroller) => { this.scroller = scroller }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
 }
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need this? I might be wrong but it sounds like the wrong approach to a simpler solution.

Comment: So I wanted to get the width of all the children combined so I could set a total width on the container this.scroller. That's really the reason why.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `refs`. Although you should avoid touching the DOM until and unless there is no other way. But here we go.

Give your child components a ref which is escape hatch provided by React to access the DOM(with a warning to use other methods before coming to this).

**Child Component**

```
class ChildComp extends Component {
  getWidth = () => {
     //Access the node here and get the width
     return this.childNode.offsetWidth(); //or clientWidth();
  } 
  render() {
     return (
       <div ref={(r) => {this.childNode = r}}>
       </div>
     );
  }
}
```

**Parent Component:**

```
class ParentComp extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
     //Access the child component function from here
     this.childComponent.getWidth();
  }
  render() {
     return (
       <ChildComp 
          ref={(r) => {this.childComponent = r}} />
     );
  }
}
```

But do remember use the above method when there is no way of getting the thing done declaratively.

Comment: Thanks Fyre,  yea I had started to use refs on the children but thought it was a little over worked solution to have to add all this to the children to get a simple width. Sorry I don't fully understand is your statement "Although you should avoid touching the DOM until and unless there is no other way". Unless someone else chimes in here but it looks like there isn't any other way. Also what's up with not touching a DOM element. React never says don't touch the DOM. If you didn't touch the DOM element how would you find its width ?? Thanks for your solution.

Comment: The reason for not touching the DOM is DOM operations are expensive and if you misuse it your performance will really suffer, so you should let React handle the DOM operations as its optimal. Getting the width is the scenario where there is no other way(unless you are using fixed widths which you can store somewhere in JS configs). Can you please let me know why this is  an overworked solution. If we need something from the DOM's dynamic property like width or height, we need to get hold of the DOM node and react's way of doing that is using refs. Please do let me know if other ways exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that technically it doesn't seem possible. The JSX

```
<div className="large-box"/>
```

does not refer to DOM element, (which has a width once it's been rendered) but to a React element, which is an in-memory object describing how to *make* an DOM element. Since the React element isn't rendered or even connected to the actual DOM in the browser, it can't know the width.

Remember that React can be rendered on the server -- there's no way the server can know what the browser on different computer is going to display.

I'd also echo what Pedro Nascimento noted -- this solution is probably best solved some other way, but without context, it's difficult to help.

Comment: React can be rendered on the server but he is doing the processing in componentDidMount which is vaild as it only runs on the client.

Comment: So all i'm trying to do is get the width of the containers children. Pretty simple in most JS frameworks. Thanks for clarifying the above but I am using a componentDidMount so the component should be mounted along with its children. The reason I want the children widths is to get the total width of items in the Container so I can set a fixed width on the container for horizontal scrolling purposes.

Comment: Gotcha. Is there an alternative, like using css [overflow-y](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) to set up a scroll area automatically?

Comment: Well yea if you use overflow-x so you can have your horizontal scroll bar. But I need to set a width on the container but in order to set the width you need to first know the sum of the total width of the children inside it.

Comment: What I was thinking about was this kind of thing -- https://jsfiddle.net/stevecooperorg/eoju099e/4/ -- where there is an area on the right with a horizontal scroller in it, but there's no need to set the overall width because you guide the browser with this CSS:  `width: auto; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; white-space: nowrap;` If that's not your use case, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

then try to get the ref of "DivColorOpacy"! and put whatever you want on parent and cutom your behavior. That's silly but that do the job.

with this css

```css
.DivColorOpacy{
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
  position: relative;
}
```

```
import { Component } from "react";
import * as React from "react";


interface DivColorOpacyProps {
    backgroundColor: string,
    opacity: number,
}
export class DivColorOpacy extends Component<DivColorOpacyProps, any>{
    componentDidMount(){

    }
    render() {
        const { backgroundColor, opacity } = this.props;
        return <div className="DivColorOpacy">
            {this.props.children}
            <div style={{
                position: "absolute",
                zIndex: -1,
                backgroundColor,
                opacity,
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                top:0
            }} />
            
        </div>
    }
}
```